How to put a trigger on an specific cell only?
I have a problem with my trigger for my checkbox. Once I clicked a checkbox it opens a dialog but the problem is I cannot put the trigger on a specific cell where my checkbox is inserted. all the checkbox on the sheet activates the trigger when I clicked on it.
Here is my trigger,
function editHandler(e = {range: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange()}) {

  if(e.range.isChecked()){
    uploadFile(); // Core statement
    Utilities.sleep(2000); // Waits 2 seconds
    e.range.uncheck(); // Uncheck the checked checkbox
  }

}

I want to put,
getSheetByName("Request Input").getRange('C10')

But I don't know where to put it and how to make it work. Please help me. Thanks

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, is the following modification close to your expected result?
Modified script:
In this modification, when a checkbox of "C10" of "Request Input" sheet is checked, the script below the if statement is run.
function editHandler(e = { range: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange() }) {
  const { range } = e;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() != "Request Input" || range.getA1Notation() != "C10" || !range.isChecked()) return;

  uploadFile(); // Core statement
  Utilities.sleep(2000); // Waits 2 seconds
  range.uncheck(); // Uncheck the checked checkbox

}


sorry bro but your code is not working

@Bugsy Thank you for replying. About sorry bro but your code is not working, I apologize for the inconvenience. First, I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. You want to run uploadFile() when a checkbox of "C10" of "Request Input" sheet is clicked. And, your function has already been installed as the OnEdit trigger. Is my understanding correct? Because my proposed modification works for this situation. But, if my understanding was not correct, I apologize. At that time, please provide the details of your expected result.

@Bugsy By the way, in my proposed answer, it supposes that your function uploadFile() works fine. Please be careful about this. Can I think that your function uploadFile() works fine?

@Bugsy If my understanding was correct and you say but your code is not working, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your current issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? By the way, I tested my proposed script again. Unfortunately, for the function editHandler installed as the OnEdit trigger, and when a checkbox of "C10" of "Request Input" sheet is clicked, the script below the if statement is run. I apologize for this situation.

my code is working fine but my problem is that I have two checkbox and both of them when I clicked is running the trigger I just want to run the trigger when the checkbox on cell C10 is checked. I tried your code but when I run it both of my check box is not activating the trigger.

@Bugsy Thank you for replying. About I tried your code but when I run it both of my check box is not activating the trigger., in this case, it is required to confirm your situation. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Because when I tested my script, unfortunately, no issue occurred. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, I asked about providing the sample Spreadsheet.

@Bugsy I'm worried that in your situation, the other functions might be related to your current issue. Because the simple script in my answer works fine. But, unfortunately, I do not know your actual situation. So, I asked about providing the sample Spreadsheet to confirm your actual situation. I apologize for my poor skill again.

try my template https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k7LtuBKmW7Nmt6-vfrWQ-6E_mMTGTIto_e5byReDmXA/copy

@Bugsy Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot open it. Can you confirm it again?

please do try this instead https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k7LtuBKmW7Nmt6-vfrWQ-6E_mMTGTIto_e5byReDmXA/copy

@Bugsy Thank you for replying. I could copy your sample Spreadsheet. I said can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your situation?  in my comment. So, I believe that your provided sample Spreadsheet includes the current script for correctly replicating your situation. When I saw your current script, unfortunately, my proposed script was not used. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. Please use my proposed modification and test it again. By the way, in your Spreadsheet, no sheet "Request Input". Please be careful about this.

it is now working. Thank you for your code it helps alot. THANKS!

@Bugsy About it is now working. Thank you for your code it helps alot. THANKS!, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

@Bugsy you should accept this answer Bro.

And onEdit for a given sheet and row and column
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == "SheetName" && e.range.columnStart == column && e.range.rowStart == row) {
   //put code here
}

